# Can we get Community Ads?

Tags: support, status-deferred, promotion

We would like to offer Community Ads for [Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) and as stated in the bylaws we must <del>sacrifice 20 sheep to the great Baal</del> create a meta post requesting such a thing.

> (If your site does not yet have a community promotion post on its meta, contact me to request one, or simply post a meta request asking for it to be created.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traditionally, we've only run these on graduated sites (with one temporary exception when building requirements for the Community Bulletin board). Since they take quite a bit of involvement to be useful, it's really not worth anyone's time for smaller sites - you're better off focusing on other avenues for promotion.

Comment: As of now, it may be more useful.  Note the number of people who are on the site.  It's almost out of beta.